# Is it a bad practice to call onBackPressed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

There is a "x" / "<" button for an activity with fragment, when backStackEntryCount == 1, it shows "x" to let user close the activity, otherwise it shows "<" to let user back to previous fragment.

Is it a bad practice if I call onBackPressed when the button onClicked?
or should I check the backStackEntryCount to decide finish the activity or popBackStack?

Comment: You can manage back press on OnBackPress in your activity with backstack entry count based on your need. it is based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you don't need to cal OnBackPressed() in your activity on button press.

On press "X" button you can simply call finish() to close activity and while press "<" button just Pop the fragment from stack.